# How to insert a specific UUID in h2 database?

Tags: mysql, h2, uuid

I need to insert some default data in my database. I am using Spring Boot with the Flyway integration. For testing, I use H2. For production MySQL will be used.

I have made separate Flyway migration scripts so I can use database specific stuff for the default data (Creating the tables is done in a common script).

For MySQL, I have something like this:

```
INSERT INTO survey_definition (id, name, period) 
VALUES (0x2D1EBC5B7D2741979CF0E84451C5BBB1, 'disease-activity', 'P1M');
```

How can I do the same for H2?

I only found the `RANDOM_UUID()` function, which works, but I need use a known UUID because I am using it as foreign keys in further statements.

Comment: Using a different database for testing than production seems like a disaster in the making. How can you be sure your code will run correctly on MySQL unless you test on it first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best if you use a syntax that works for all databases. I think most databases don't support the `0x` syntax. For H2, this would work:

```
INSERT INTO survey_definition (id, name, period) 
VALUES ('2D1EBC5B7D2741979CF0E84451C5BBB1', 'disease-activity', 'P1M');
```

But to get a cross-database syntax, you may need to create a user defined function (for example `uuid`) and then use:

```
INSERT INTO survey_definition (id, name, period) 
VALUES (uuid('2D1EBC5B7D2741979CF0E84451C5BBB1'), 'disease-activity', 'P1M');
```

Comment: Can you explain the user defined function in more detail? How to create that and how does it look?

Comment: That depends on the database. For H2, it would have one parameter, and return that parameter.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I solved my issue