# Generate UUID values by default for each row on column of UUID type in H2 Database Engine

Tags: default, h2, uuid

In the [H2 database](http://h2database.com), on a table with a column of [UUID data type](http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#uuid_type), how do we specify that we want H2 to generate a [UUID value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) by default when an `INSERT` omits that field?

I know how to [generate a UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID--). 
I have read the Question, [*How to insert a specific UUID in h2 database?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36494510/642706).

My question is about how to ask H2 to generate the UUID value on my behalf.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## In SQL

You can use built-in function [`RANDOM_UUID()`](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#random_uuid):

```
create table test(id int primary key, data uuid default random_uuid());
insert into test(id) values(1);
select * from test;
```

Note that using the UUID type (or any other randomly generated data that doesn't have any natural ordering) as the primary key will result in performance problems if there are more than a few million rows (with relational databases in general, not just with H2).

Comment: Hi, would you mind source the part about performance issue? I am working with reactive programming and I most likely have to rely on database (Postgre) to generate a random UUID. I would love to avoid performance issues after few months of release.

Comment: See for example https://blog.programster.org/mysql-performance-when-using-uuid-for-primary-key Performance impact depends many things; for PostgreSQL I think the impact is lower than for H2 / MySQL / MS SQL Server, but I'm afraid I don't understand why exactly so far. The problem doesn't show up if the ids are somewhat ordered, as for example in https://github.com/anthonynsimon/timeflake

Answer (score 25):

## In JPA/Hibernate

After googling for hours I've created a simple solution for [JPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Persistence) or [Hibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Persistence#Hibernate), according to @Thomas Mueller.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
)
@Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
@ColumnDefault("random_uuid()")
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
@Getter
@Setter
private UUID id;
```

So `@Type(type = "uuid-char")` makes your field a `VARCHAR(255)` if you need it (it's binary by default)

And `@ColumnDefault("random_uuid()")` puts the default value for generated table DDL

Comment: Perfect answer, saves a ton of time. Thanks a lot.