# Liquibase - insert rows with uuid

Tags: sql, liquibase

I have two tables declared as follows:

```
<changeSet author="istvan" id="country-table-changelog">
    <createTable tableName="country">
        <column name="id" type="uuid">
            <constraints nullable="false" unique="true" />
        </column>
        <column name="name" type="varchar">
            <constraints nullable="false" unique="true" />
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="istvan" id="region-table-changelog">
    <createTable tableName="region">
        <column name="id" type="uuid" >
            <constraints nullable="false" unique="true" />
        </column>
        <column name="country_id" type="uuid">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="name" type="varchar">
            <constraints nullable="false" unique="true" />
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="istvan" id="region-country-foreign-key-constraint">
    <addForeignKeyConstraint 
        baseTableName="region"
        baseColumnNames="country_id"
        referencedTableName="country"
        referencedColumnNames="id"
        constraintName="fk_region_country"
        onDelete="CASCADE" 
        onUpdate="RESTRICT"/>
</changeSet>
```

I want to fill both tables from liquibase changelog file with some values like:

```
INSERT INTO country VALUES('aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa', 'HUNGARY');
INSERT INTO region VALUES('bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb', 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa', 'Baranya');
```

In the example I used aaaa's and bbbb's just because of simplicity. I want to generate those UUID's by the DBMS.

What is the best way to do it? Do I have to use SQL in my changelog files or is it possible with XML? I prefer DBMS independent solution like XML or JSON.

My second question is that how can I declare a column with UUID that creates the UUID on insert. Something like:

```
<column name="id" type="uuid" value="??? GENERATE UUID ???">
    <constraints nullable="false" unique="true" />
</column>
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can do this by using properties that are defined depending on the current DBMS.

```
<property name="uuid_type" value="uuid" dbms="postgresql"/>
<property name="uuid_type" value="uniqueidentifier" dbms="mssql"/>
<property name="uuid_type" value="RAW(16)" dbms="oracle"/>

<property name="uuid_function" value="uid.uuid_generate_v4()" dbms="postgresql"/>
<property name="uuid_function" value="NEWID()" dbms="mssql"/>
<property name="uuid_function" value="sys_guid()" dbms="oracle"/>
```

Then use those properties when defining the table:

```
<column name="id" type="${uuid_type}" defaultValueComputed="${uuid_function}">
    <constraints nullable="false" unique="true" />
</column>
```

Note that you need to use `defaultValueComputed`, **not** `value`

If the column is defined with a default value, just leave it out in your insert statements and the database will then generate the UUID when inserting.

Comment: The first part works. It inserts Hungary with `919d39e4-2387-4926-91d5-595ebe0eea07` id. However, for the second insert it gives the following exception: `ERROR: insert or update on table "region" violates foreign key constraint "fk_region_country" Key (country_id)=(34e4e0d8-91d8-4d52-99ae-ec42d6b0e66e) is not present in table "country"`. Usage of foreign key is clear but I don't know how to work with it in liquibase. Here is the code I use:  
`<column name="country_id" type="${uuid_type}" defaultValueComputed="${uuid_function}">
       <constraints nullable="false" />
   </column>` Thx

Comment: @FarkasIstván - I'm receiving the same error. Hopefully I'll find an answer for it soon, but in the meantime, if you have it figured out please let me know.

Comment: For Oracle, shouldn't it be `RAW(16)` rather than `RAW(32)` ? (yes, Oracle used to have a bug in their online docs in this respect, but it has been corrected). See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions202.htm#SQLRF06120.

Comment: I got it to work with postgres (14.5) when defining the function property with `value="gen_random_uuid()"` (otherwise I got errors about the uid namespace)

Comment: Late comment: @FarkasIstván You cannot insert rows with FK relationships from a static file, without specifying the ID's. How would Liquibase figure out which region should belong to which country?

Answer (score 5):

For MySQL, put your property just before changeSet tag:

```
    <property name="u_id" value="uuid()" dbms="mysql"/>
```

then

```
    <column name="ID" type="varchar(255)" valueComputed="${u_id}"/>
```

NOTE: here `valueComputed` is used, not `defaultValueComputed`.

Answer (score 2):

For me helped this (postgres 14.2):

```
<property name="uuid_function" value="gen_random_uuid()" dbms="postgresql"/>
<column name="id" valueComputed="${uuid_function}"/>
```

Comment: I get the "function gen_random_uuid() does not exist" exception. Can you help me?

Comment: @MichaelSparrow first thing is to check if your Postgres version supports it. You can find related information here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html It looks like this function is supported in 13-16 version

Comment: This indeed was the issue. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Some databases supports UUID columns: [Generate UUID values by default for each row on column of UUID type in H2 Database Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112332/generate-uuid-values-by-default-for-each-row-on-column-of-uuid-type-in-h2-databa)

I don't think that Liquibase has embedded UUID generator, have a look at defaultValueComputed/valueComputed property for column (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html) + DB function to generate UUID

Answer (score 0):

Like Rammgarot noted, since we are dealing with columns that need to have unique values, we should use `valueComputed` instead of `defaultValueComputed`.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the provided answers didn't help me **in case of MySQL**, but I was able to work it out using another approach - using triggers.

```
<changeSet author="nberezovski" id="1">
        <createTable tableName="test">
            <column name="id" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="description" type="varchar(255)">
            ...
        </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="nberezovski" id="2">
        <sql splitStatements="false">
            CREATE TRIGGER insert_test
            BEFORE INSERT ON test
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
            IF (NEW.id IS NULL) THEN
            SET NEW.id = UUID();
            END IF;
            END;
        </sql>
</changeSet>
```

After that, each manual insert only of values for `description` MySQL automatically generated an `id` for me. For example:

```
insert into test(description) values('some description');
```

Also that approach helped in loading data using `loadData`

Answer (score 0):

For SQL SERVER works

```
<column name="uuid" valueComputed="newid()" />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).