# I found an easy way to generate pseudo-random MySQL IDs, what's wrong with this approach?

Tags: mysql, random

There's business intelligence risk to exposing auto-incremented IDs to users. The methods that I commonly see people using to solve this are:

- use GUID/MD5 (larger and slower than 4 byte INT)
- generate integer, check for collision, repeat (slow, have to lock table)
- expose "public" ID in the application (easy to leak actual ID, might be slow)

Instead, I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

Then, every time I insert a row, I'd manually insert the ID like this:

```
insert into `foo` (id) values (
    last_insert_id((0xe8e5 * last_insert_id()) % power(2, 32))
);
```

The formula is a linear congruential generator. My understanding is that it would generate a pseudo-random integer between 1 and 2^32, with no collisions unless all 2^32-1 integers are exhausted. The parameter `0xe8e5` is from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.05304.pdf

Surprisingly, this even works with bulk inserts. Also, I tried inserting 100,000 rows and there weren't collisions.

I haven't seen anyone else do this before, are there potential issues with this?

Comment: Is it worked for insert multiple rows? since , `last_insert_id` returns the value generated for the **first** inserted row only.

Comment: Also `last_insert_id` is 0 for the first row and `last_insert_id((0xe8e5 * last_insert_id()) % power(2, 32))` always return 0. What's wrong here in my test and yours?

Comment: @MajidHajibaba Leo is using `last_insert_id(expr)`, which sets the value implicitly and would return a different value for each row (similar to a function that gets evaluated for each row.) `last_insert_id()` on its own would indeed not work as expected for multi-row inserts.

Comment: Thanks @Solarflare. Also the first value of last_insert_id() must not be zero.

Comment: Yes it works with bulk inserts, and you'll need to seed last_insert_id with a positive value

Comment: How much of risk is it to use auto-increment ID's? Because such risks are usually mitigated with cryptographic solutions. A LCG is not hard to solve given one or two outputs, and given the output of an LCG the position in the sequence can be determined easily for smallish LCGs like this, in which case you're no better than using an auto-incremented ID.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a unique and random number for a primary key in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51167523/how-to-generate-a-unique-and-random-number-for-a-primary-key-in-sql)

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I just don't want to make it too easy, e.g. cryptographic would be nice, but might be diminishing returns. That solution just says to use UUID, which I mentioned in the question.

Comment: No, there were several answers, the [the last one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56120914/238704) mentions the lcg among other things.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk - Your links are _not_ applicable to MySQL.

Comment: Even if that code is correct... Who is going to maintain that code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a general technical issue with your specific approach, as [`last_insert_id()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) is session-specific. That means another session will not be informed about changes to that value, and will most likely reuse an id. Also you will have to initialize `last_insert_id()` when the session starts. Additionally, every use of an auto-increment column (for maybe a different table) will reset the value.

You should also be aware that, although it will obscure your values, this is not necessarily secure, see e.g. [How can I determine the initial values of pseudo-random number generator if the sequence is given?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/1845).

Comment: Didn't know it's session-specific, thanks!

Comment: The security issue can be solved by using a strong encryption.  Use AES to encrypt 0, 1, 2, 3, ... and you will get non-repeating secure 128 bit numbers.

Answer (score 1):

- I believe that MySQL's `RAND()` is a simple LCG with a period of 2^30.
- Check out `UUID_SHORT()`.
  See this for how "unique" it is (or isn't):
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short
- A one-way hash, like `MD5()` is virtually unhackable.  Something like `MD5(6))`  `select benchmark(1000000, MD5(NOW(6)));` says that it takes about 0.2 *microseconds* on my machine.  I would think that that is plenty fast.  Compare that to maybe 1000 microseconds to store a row containing the value.
- `LENGTH(UNHEX(MD5(NOW(6))))` = 16 bytes, so not terribly big.
- If you have 9 trillion md5's, there is only one chance in 9 trillion that there is an unexpected dup.