# Specify a default value for a primary key column of type UUID in H2 Database Engine?

Tags: primary-key, h2, uuid, create-table

This SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE product_ ( 
    pkey_ UUID PRIMARY KEY
) ;
```

…successfully creates a table.

But I want new rows to default to a UUId generated by [`RANDOM_UUID()`](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#random_uuid) as shown on [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41121779/642706).

```sql
CREATE TABLE product_ ( 
    pkey_ UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() 
) ;
```

But this fails with an error:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_ ( 
>     PKEY_ UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT[*] RANDOM_UUID() 
>   ) ;  "; expected "HASH, AUTO_INCREMENT, NOT, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"; SQL statement:

What is the cause and solution for this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Arguments ordering

The order in which the arguments appears matters.

As you can see in the documentation on [*Column Definition*](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#column_definition), the syntax chart shows that `DEFAULT` must appear *before* the `PRIMARY KEY`. Swap those two parts to fix.

```sql
CREATE TABLE product_ ( 
    pkey_ UUID DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() PRIMARY KEY 
) ;
```