# Return primary key value generated by default in H2 database upon INSERT of new row, for UUID type column

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, h2, uuid

When using a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) data [type](http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#uuid_type) as the primary key of a table, and asking H2 to [generate each UUID value by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41112332/642706) upon INSERT of a new record, how does one **access the value of the newly generated UUID** value?

I am using plain JDBC 4.x in a Java app, if that helps with a solution.

---

I know [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html?highlight=SCOPE_IDENTITY&search=scope_ident#scope_identity) function returns a `long` for a key generated on a column marked as `IDENTITY` for an auto-incrementing sequence number. But I am using UUID rather than an incrementing number as my primary key column types.

Comment: are you using spring-data or a simple JDBC?

Comment: @YCF_L Straight JDBC, nor ORM, no additional framework.

Comment: Have you tried [Statement#getGeneratedKeys](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()) ? This is the basic method available in JDBC.

Comment: @krokodilko Thanks, using standard JDBC did the trick. Explained in Answers by me and by YCF_L.

Comment: This Question turns out to be quite close to this other, but this Question here is specific to H2 Database Engine here: [*How to get the insert ID in JDBC?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1915166/642706)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `Statement::getGeneratedKeys`

As seen in comments and the [correct Answer by YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53907260/642706), the solution lies in standard JDBC: Call [`Statement::getGeneratedKeys`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()). This yields a [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html) of the key values generated by default in the previous use of that statement. This works with [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), and works with auto-generating UUID values as the primary key.

## `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`

The catch is that by default you do *not* get back generated keys. You must activate this feature by passing an extra argument to your [`Connection::prepareStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,int)) call. The extra argument is an `int`, using a constant defined on the `Statement` interface, [`Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS). In modern Java that would have likely have been defined as an [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html), but [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) dates back to the earliest days of Java, so the argument is a simple `int`.

## Example app

Here is a complete example app, in a single file.

```
package work.basil.example.h2.auto_uuid;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.UUID;

public class App {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        App app = new App();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt ( ) {
        
        try {
            Class.forName( "org.h2.Driver" );
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:h2:mem:auto_uuid_example_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" ) ; // Set `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` to `-1` to keep in-memory database in existence after connection closes.
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
        ) {
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE person_ ( \n" +
                    "  pkey_ UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() PRIMARY KEY , \n" +
                    "  name_ VARCHAR NOT NULL \n" +
                    ");";
            stmt.execute( sql );

            // Insert row.
            sql = "INSERT INTO person_ ( name_ ) \n";
            sql += "VALUES ( ? ) \n";
            sql += ";";
            try (
                    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( sql , Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS ) ;
            ) {

                pstmt.setString( 1 , "Jesse Johnson" );
                pstmt.executeUpdate();

                ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
                System.out.println( "INFO - Reporting generated keys." );
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    UUID uuid = rs.getObject( 1 , UUID.class );
                    System.out.println( "generated keys: " + uuid );
                }

            }

            // Dump all rows.
            System.out.println( "INFO - Reporting all rows in table `person_`." );
            sql = "SELECT * FROM person_";
            try ( ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ; ) {
                while ( rs.next() ) {
                    UUID pkey = rs.getObject( "pkey_" , UUID.class );
                    String name = rs.getString( "name_" );
                    System.out.println( "Person: " + pkey + " | " + name );
                }
            }

        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

When run.

> INFO - Reporting generated keys.
>
> generated keys: 9c6ce984-151b-4e64-8334-d96e17be9525
>
> INFO - Reporting all rows in table `person_`.
>
> Person: 9c6ce984-151b-4e64-8334-d96e17be9525 | Jesse Johnson

If you want to insert multiple rows at a time, rather than one, use batching. See: [*Java: Insert multiple rows into MySQL with PreparedStatement*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4355046/642706).

If you have multiple columns being auto-generated, rather than just the one single UUID column seen here, see the [other Answer by YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53907260/642706).

Comment: as always nice question and answer, I forgot to use `rs.getObject( 1 , UUID.class );` :)

Answer (score 4):

## Specify name(s) of generated columns

When preparing your statement, you can optionally pass an array of the names of columns for which a default value is being generated. For just your single primary key column, that means an array of one value.

See the method:
[`Connection::prepareStatement​( String sql, String[] columnNames )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,java.lang.String%5B%5D))

Example code.

```
// here you can specify the list of returned attributes, in your case just the data
String[] returnedAttributes = {"data"};
String insertQuery = "insert into test(id) values(1);";
try 
(
    PreparedStatement insertStatement = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery, returnedAttributes);
) 
{
    int rows = insertStatement.executeUpdate();
    if (rows == 0) 
    {
        throw new SQLException("Failed of insertion");
    }
    try (ResultSet rs = insertStatement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
        if (rs.next()) 
        {
             java.util.UUID uuid = (java.util.UUID) rs.getObject("data");
             System.out.println(uuid);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**

to get the UUID type you have to use `getObjct(..)` and cast it to `java.util.UUID` as stated in the documentation of [H2 UUID Type](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#uuid_type)

> Universally unique identifier. This is a 128 bit value. To store
> values, use PreparedStatement.setBytes, setString, or setObject(uuid)
> (where uuid is a java.util.UUID). **ResultSet.getObject will return a
> java.util.UUID.**

---

My example based on the link you shared in your question [Generate UUID values by default for each row on column of UUID type in H2 Database Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112332/generate-uuid-values-by-default-for-each-row-on-column-of-uuid-type-in-h2-databa)

Comment: Thanks for educating me. Good Answer, but I think in most cases where we have just a single column being auto-generated the approach in my Answer is simpler, calling this [`Connection::prepareStatement `](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,int)) (2nd argument of int) instead of that [`Connection::prepareStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,java.lang.String%5B%5D)) (2nd argument of array).

Comment: You are welcome @Basil Bourque I learn also from you a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

To return UUID from resultset you could use FINAL TABLE:

```
SELECT ID FROM FINAL TABLE ( INSERT INTO PERSON(NAME) VALUES('Joe'))
```